# A purely imaginary product and a fraction involving an odd multiple of π

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

> Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.  Prove: if $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{20} (\cos(k\theta) + i \sin(k\theta)) = i$, then there exists an integer $k$ such that $\theta = \left(\frac{\pi+2\pi k}{420}\right)$. You may use the fact $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm stuck on how to deal with $k=20$ and the number $420$.

Please show me the complete answer!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I've taken the liberty to edit your post.  The title does not need to present the entire problem statement; that's what the body of the Question should do, in a fairly self-contained fashion.  You might be interested in [this introduction to posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  If I haven't made a mistake in transcribing your formulas, the image of the problem can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos kx + i \sin k x = \mathrm{e}^{ikx}
$$
so we have 
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{20}\mathrm{e}^{ikx} = \mathrm{e}^{i\sum_{n=1}^{20}nx} = i
$$
so we have
$$
\cos (x\sum_{n=1}^{20}n) + i\sin(x\sum_{n=1}^{20}n) = i
$$
or we have 
$$\sin(x\sum_{n=1}^{20}n) = 1 \\ \cos (x\sum_{n=1}^{20}n) = 0$$
solve for $x$ using $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

To solve we have
$$
\cos\left(\frac{(2k+1)}{2}\pi\right) = 0\;\;\forall \;k \geq 0
$$comparing arguments
$$
\frac{(2k+1)}{2}\pi = x \sum_{n=1}^{20}n = x\frac{20\cdot 21}{2}
$$
so we have
$$
(2k+1)\pi = 20\cdot 21 x = 420 x
$$
re-arranging
$$
x = \frac{\pi + 2\pi k}{420}\;\;\forall \; k \geq 0
$$

Comment: but after solving it ,the result is pi+4kpi/420 instead of pi+2kpi/420. I don;t know whats going wronggg

Comment: See the edits above.

Answer (score 0):

when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$\text{z}=\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i=\left|\text{z}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{n}\right)i}=\left|\text{z}\right|\cos\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\right)+\left|\text{z}\right|\sin\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)\right)i$$
Where $\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$,$\arg\left(\text{z}\right)$ is the complex argument of $\text{z}$ and $\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$

---

So, when $\text{k}\space\wedge\space\theta\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\cos\left(\text{k}\theta\right)+\sin\left(\text{k}\theta\right)i=e^{\text{k}\theta i}$$

We get, when $\text{a}\space\wedge\space\text{b}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{b}>\text{a}$:

$$\text{P}_\theta\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)=\prod_{\text{k}=\text{a}}^\text{b}\left(\cos\left(\text{k}\theta\right)+\sin\left(\text{k}\theta\right)i\right)=\prod_{\text{k}=\text{a}}^\text{b}e^{\text{k}\theta i}=$$
$$e^{\text{a}\theta i}\times e^{\left(\text{a}+1\right)\theta i}\times\dots\times e^{\left(\text{b}-1\right)\theta i}\times e^{\text{b}\theta i}=$$
$$\exp\left(\text{a}\theta i+\left(\text{a}+1\right)\theta i+\dots+\left(\text{b}-1\right)\theta i+\text{b}\theta i\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\left(\text{a}+\left(\text{a}+1\right)+\dots+\left(\text{b}-1\right)+\text{b}\right)\theta i\right)=$$

We know:

$$\text{a}+\left(\text{a}+1\right)+\dots+\left(\text{b}-1\right)+\text{b}=\sum_{\text{q}=\text{a}}^\text{b}\text{q}=\frac{\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\left(1-\text{a}+\text{b}\right)}{2}$$

So:

$$\text{P}_\theta\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)=\exp\left\{\frac{\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\left(1-\text{a}+\text{b}\right)}{2}\cdot\theta i\right\}$$

And when we have that:

$$\Re\left[\text{P}_\theta\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)\right]=0$$

You've to solve:

$$\cos\left(\frac{\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\left(1-\text{a}+\text{b}\right)}{2}\cdot\theta\right)=0$$